# How to show the selected item object inside the form factory in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I am using the [crud library of Aljandro](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/crud-ui-add-on/5.0.0), and Vaadin 21.0.3

When I select a user (transporter in my example) from the crud grid table, the details show successfully.
But how can I get the selected transporter's object from inside the form itself, so I can show relations?

For example, if I have the transporter object inside the from factory, I would create a checkbox list to present the drivers [relationship is OneToMany]

Here is the code

```java
        DefaultCrudFormFactory<Transporter> formFactory = new DefaultCrudFormFactory<>(Transporter.class) {
            @Override
            protected void configureForm(FormLayout formLayout, List<HasValueAndElement> fields) {
                Component nameField = (Component) fields.get(0);
                formLayout.setColspan(nameField, 2);
            }
        };
...

        formFactory.setFieldProvider("drivers",
                new CheckBoxGroupProvider<>("Drivers",
                        formFactory.getNewInstanceSupplier().get().getDrivers(),   <<<<<< How to get the selected Transporter object? 
                        Driver::getFullName));
```

Does anyone have an example of crud with relation?

or, How to show the selected transporter's object inside the form factory?

Comment: Looking at the [code base](https://github.com/alejandro-du/crudui/blob/master/add-on/src/main/java/org/vaadin/crudui/form/CrudFormFactory.java) the interface `CrudFormFactory<T>` gives access to `SerializableSupplier<T> getNewInstanceSupplier()`, so calling this method and then `get()` on that supplier should give you a new instance of `Transporter`.

Comment: @Avec Thanks, but that gives a "new" empty instance of Transporter. What I want is to get the selected instance of transporter.

I can get the selected transporter inside grid.addSelectionListener.. using e.getFirstSelectedItem() ... but how can I update the listBox inside the formFactory.setFieldProvider?

Comment: Sorry I do not know this addon. Maybe you need to ask Alejandro if nobody can give you an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Maybe you want to override the `buildNewForm` method that accepts a domain object? Have you checked the archived forum thread? https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/14437640/crud-ui-add-on?page=5